# Displaying a number of text boxes based on user selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to display a number of text boxes depending on what number the user selects from the drop down box. So if the user selects 1 then 1 box will appear, 2 then 2 boxes will appear etc.

My drop down -

```
<select name="numNames" id="numNames">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And when the user selects a number i want this to be displayed:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="Name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 input">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required">
  </div>
</div>
```

The code from @Elise Chant is what is was looking but when i place it in the editor as below it doesn't work but does work in the example that she linked.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = '<div class="form-group">' + 
'<label for="Name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>' +
'<div class="col-sm-8 input">' +
'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required">' +
'</div>' +
'</div>';

$('#numNames').on('change', function(e) {
var numSelected = $(this).val();
appendControls(numSelected);
});

function appendControls(num) {
$('#elcontainer').empty();
for (var i=0; i<Number(num); i++) {
 $('#elcontainer').append(el);
} 
}

</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<select name="numNames" id="numNames">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="elcontainer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/zewadupivi/1/edit?js,output

```
var el = '<div class="form-group">' + 
 '<label for="Name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label>' +
  '<div class="col-sm-8 input">' +
   '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required">' +
  '</div>' +
'</div>';

$('#numNames').on('change', function(e) {
  var numSelected = Number($(this).val());
  appendControls(numSelected);
});

function appendControls(num) {
  $('#elcontainer').empty();
  for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
     $('#elcontainer').append(el);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work when i try to run it in my browser? Any idea why it does this? As i can see that it works in the demo you linked.

Comment: @OUDK, do you test locally? If so, add: http: before //code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: @nevermind tried that also. Still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @OUDK, then, last try: wrap your code inside doc.ready: https://api.jquery.com/ready/ it must work. :)

Comment: @nevermind unfortunately that didn't work either. It works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/5yup5kj4/ but when i try to put the javascript into my html file as above it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optSel = $("option:selected", this);
    var valSel = Number(this.value);
    for(var i = 0; i < valSel ; i++) {
        $("body").append('<div class="form-group"><label for="Name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name:</label><div class="col-sm-8 input"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required"></div></div>');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/0ofkdfop/